# Referencing Control Objects Created in Different Module

Tags: vba, excel

dr (no circumstantial details): I am trying to reference a control created programmatically in another module, but it is throwing

> "Compile Error: Variable not defined."

Here's what I'm trying to do (and perhaps my approach is wrong entirely, if so, let me know): I am trying to create a userform that uses a listbox to act as a menu in which the user can select an item and see the controls (labels, textboxes) relevant to that item. For instance: item "General Information" would a submitter name, department, date, etc; item "Report request" would have report application, desired app name, etc. Selecting "General Information" on the listbox should .visible=true the frame housing the "GI" controls and hide other frames, and selecting "Report Request" item would .visible=false General Information frame but .visible=true Report Request frame, and so on.

Because I want the controls to be placed in the same place on the userform, I created them all programmatically in a Construct module. It looks like this:

```
Public Sub GeneralInformationCreator()

Dim i As Integer
Dim labelGeneral As MSForms.Label
Dim frameGeneral As MSForms.Frame
Dim frameRequestInformation As MSForms.Frame
Dim frameSubmitterInformation As MSForms.Frame
Dim labelAppSelect As MSForms.Label
Dim listAppSelect As MSForms.ListBox
Dim labelDateSelect As MSForms.Label
Dim comboMonthSelect, comboDaySelect, comboYearSelect As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim labelSubmitterFName, labelSubmitterLName As MSForms.Label
Dim inputSubmitterFName, inputSubmitterLName As MSForms.TextBox
Dim labelSponsorFName, labelSponsorLName As MSForms.Label
Dim inputSponsorFName, inputSponsorLName As MSForms.TextBox
Dim labelDepartmentName As MSForms.Label
Dim inputDepartmentName As MSForms.TextBox

Set labelGeneral = formRequestWizard.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "labelGeneral", True)
    With labelGeneral
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Top = 12
        .Left = 192
        .Height = 14.25
        .Width = 42
        .Caption = "General Information"
        .Name = labelGeneral
    End With

Set frameGeneral = formRequestWizard.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "frameGeneral", True)
    With frameGeneral
        .Top = 30
        .Left = 192
        .Height = 310
        .Width = 384
        .Caption = ""
        .BorderColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)

        Set frameRequestInformation = frameGeneral.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "frameRequestInformation", True)
            With frameRequestInformation
                .Top = 15
                .Left = 15
                .Height = 100
                .Width = 350
                .Caption = "Request Information"
                .BorderStyle = 1
                .BorderColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

                Set labelAppSelect = frameRequestInformation.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "labelAppSelect", True)
                    With labelAppSelect
                        .Caption = "Select an application:"
                        .Top = 15
                        .Left = 15
                        .Width = 100
                        .Height = 20
                        .AutoSize = True
                    End With
```

The Construct methods are called at runtime using UserForm_Initialize() like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Call Construct.GeneralInformationCreator
Call Construct.ApplicationDetailsCreator

With formRequestWizard.listMenu
    .AddItem ("General Information")
    .AddItem ("Application Details")
    '.Selected(0) = True
End With

End Sub
```

**Here's the issue:** in the userform code, I have a listMenu_Change() that looks like this:

```
Private Sub listMenu_Change()

If (listMenu.Selected(0) = True) Then
    labelGeneral.Visible = True
    frameGeneral.Visible = True
Else
    labelGeneral.Visible = False
    frameGeneral.Visible = False
End If

If (listMenu.Selected(1) = True) Then
    labelAppDetails.Visible = True
    frameAppDetails.Visible = True
Else
    labelAppDetails.Visible = False
    frameAppDetails.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

Selecting an item from the listbox throws the error from the tl;dr: "Compile Error: Variable not defined" on the first variable "labelGeneral".

I have tried putting all of the script into the userform code window, and putting the control Dims outside of Subs. The research I've done has mostly led to discussions about how to create event handlers for controls created at runtime, but I've decided to place the listMenu object via the object view so I'm not sure that's applicable.

Comment: tl,dr: There are no controls named `labelGeneral`, etc. You are confusing the Form.Controls Index with the compiler’s namespace.  They are different and, specifically, the compiler’s namespace cannot be added to at runtime.  One way to workaround it is with something like `Controls!labelGeneral`.

Comment: @RBarryYoung there are, but they're scoped to `GeneralInformationCreator`. It's just a scoping-concept issue, i.e. the dirtiest fix would be to pull all these `Dim` statements at module level and make them `Public` (i.e. move from local to project/global scope).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Oops, I missed that part.  Right you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GeneralInformationCreator` should be a class in its own right - even the name says so (it's a *name* like a class/type that *is* something, not a *verb* like a procedure that *does* something).

See all these declarations you have at procedure scope, live and die at procedure scope - they're *local variables* that nobody else can see:

```
Dim labelGeneral As MSForms.Label
Dim frameGeneral As MSForms.Frame
Dim frameRequestInformation As MSForms.Frame
Dim frameSubmitterInformation As MSForms.Frame
Dim labelAppSelect As MSForms.Label
Dim listAppSelect As MSForms.ListBox
Dim labelDateSelect As MSForms.Label
Dim comboMonthSelect [As Variant], comboDaySelect [As Variant], comboYearSelect As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim labelSubmitterFName [As Variant], labelSubmitterLName As MSForms.Label
Dim inputSubmitterFName [As Variant], inputSubmitterLName As MSForms.TextBox
Dim labelSponsorFName [As Variant], labelSponsorLName As MSForms.Label
Dim inputSponsorFName [As Variant], inputSponsorLName As MSForms.TextBox
Dim labelDepartmentName As MSForms.Label
Dim inputDepartmentName As MSForms.TextBox
```

By moving them up to *instance level* fields (i.e. module-scope variables) in a class module, you can expose a `Public Property Get` accessor that makes anyone with an instance of that class able to access these objects.

So instead of this:

> ```
> Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
>
>     Call Construct.GeneralInformationCreator
>     Call Construct.ApplicationDetailsCreator
>
>     With formRequestWizard.listMenu
>         .AddItem ("General Information")
>         .AddItem ("Application Details")
>         '.Selected(0) = True
>     End With
>
> End Sub
> ```

You will have that:

```
Private generalInfoControls As New GeneralInformationCreator
Private appDetailsControls As New ApplicationDetailsCreator
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    generalInfoControls.Create Me.Controls
    appDetailsControls.Create Me.Controls

    With Me.listMenu 'don't refer to the default instance in the form's code-behind... EVER!
        .AddItem "General Information"
        .AddItem "Application Details"
        '.Selected(0) = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Where `Create` is a procedure that takes a `Controls` parameter - by giving it `Me.Controls` we are passing the collection of controls for *the current instance* of the user form, so the method can look like this:

```
Public Sub Create(ByVal parent As Controls)
    Set labelGeneral = parent.Add("Forms.Label.1", "labelGeneral", True)
        With labelGeneral
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Top = 12
            .Left = 192
            .Height = 14.25
            .Width = 42
            .Caption = "General Information"
            .Name = labelGeneral
        End With
     '...
```

Notice it's no longer *coupled* with the *default instance* of your `formRequestWizard` form, and will work with whatever form instance's `Controls` collection it's given.

I'm not sure if you're still following my train of thought here, but this means your handler can now do this:

```
Private Sub listMenu_Change()
    generalInfoControls.SetVisibility listMenu.Selected(0)
    appDetailsControls.SetVisibility listMenu.Selected(1)
End Sub
```

That implies that your `XxxxCreator` classes have a `SetVisibility` method that looks something like this:

```
Public Sub SetVisibility(ByVal isVisible As Boolean)
    labelGeneral.Visible = isVisible
    frameGeneral.Visible = isVisible
    '...
```

Comment: This is out of scope of the original question, but can you expand on "'don't refer to the default instance in the form's code-behind... EVER!"?

Comment: This is the option I went with, and it is working so far.

Answer (score 3):

Define all your variables like this:

```
Dim comboMonthSelect As MSForms.Combobox
Dim comboDaySelect As MSForms.Combobox 
Dim comboYearSelect As MSForms.ComboBox
```

With 
`Dim comboMonthSelect, comboDaySelect, comboYearSelect As MSForms.ComboBox`,
only `comboYearSelect` is declared as a `MSForms.ComboBox` and the other two as `Variant`.

---

Then write `Option Explicit` and make sure that every variable is defined in every Sub/Function. In your case is should be:

```
Dim labelGeneral As MSForms.Label
```

in the Sub `listMenu_Change`, where the error is happening. [MSDN Option Explicit reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement).

---

As a quick and dirty way, you can do something like this:

```
If (listMenu.Selected(0) = True) Then
    Controls("labelGeneral").Visible = True
    Controls("someOtherName").Visible = True
End If
```

However, this breaks completely [any MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and may cause any non-VBA people to feel dizzy and to publish things like this:

[image]

If you want to do it the "correct way", read this article form the ex-StackOverflow Documentation, it is quite nice:
http://www.riptutorial.com/vba/example/19036/best-practices.

Comment: While a good practice, it wouldn't change the runtime types (they'd be `Variant/Object/MSForms.ComboBox`); the code should still work with them being `Variant` (although that is clearly not the OP's intent).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - I have to start with something :)

Comment: `listMenu_Change` likely means to refer to the objects that live in `GeneralInformationCreator` though.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up on the variable definitions; I thought putting them on the same line before the As gave them all the same variable type. I will define them separately from now on.

I do have Option Explicit on every module. Are you saying that I should be defining labelGeneral (and the rest) in the Construct module's methods, and then also in the listMenu_Change() event?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon That is what I suspected

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - you are right, most probably this is the idea.

Comment: @Exulansis - take a look at the update, the quick and dirty way would probably work somehow.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - yup. Still, one more VBA-Dev, converted to the OOP way for UserForms... Good job! :)